# Insert GeoDataFrame into MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, geometry

I have a GeoDataFrame that looks like this:

```
       id                  name                                         theoretica descriptio                   geometry
0   1  AIS Télécom Bretagne  SRID=4326;POLYGON((-4.57083333333333 48.385326...       None  POINT (-4.57008 48.35877)
```

I am trying to insert it into a mongo database. I am using *insert_many* but it doesn't seem like to work.  A snippet of my code is this:

```
my_dataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
db = client['Marine_Database']
db.Theoritical_Coverage.insert_many(my_dataframe.to_dict('records'))
```

Is there any way I can insert this dataframe in my database?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your DataFrame in Mongo, but you have to convert your shapely object 'POINT' to a geojson point object first.
You can do this thanks to :

```
my_dataframe['geometry']= my_dataframe['geometry'].apply(lambda x:shapely.geometry.mapping(x))
```

There is a good example on how to insert your data in a database here :
https://medium.com/ambee-air-quality-blog/converting-geographical-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-mongodb-geopoint-object-12acbb00c4a